# Having issues with CASE clause in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, case

```
UPDATE main_cats set cat_order=(
    CASE         
         when cat_order='4' THEN (4-1) 
         WHEN cat_order=(4-1) THEN '4'
    END)
```

When I run the above query on the bottom data I get.

```
cat_id  cat_name     cat_order cat_visible
 0      NO MAIN CAT  0           N
 5      CLOTHES      1           N
 6      GIFTS        2           N
 7      ARTWORK      3           Y
 8      TEST CATEGO  4           N
```

I end up with

```
cat_id  cat_name     cat_order cat_visible
 0      NO MAIN CAT  0           N
 5      CLOTHES      0           N
 6      GIFTS        0           N 
 7      ARTWORK      3           Y
 8      TEST CATEGO  3           N
```

Not sure why the others go to ZERO in the CASE statement.

Comment: 4-1 is 3, right? Why leave math in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are updating the column without a where and your conditional is only setting a value in two scenarios. For the rest I would guess it assumes zero with no input. I think this could work:

```
UPDATE main_cats set cat_order=(
CASE         
     when cat_order='4' THEN (4-1) 
     WHEN cat_order=(4-1) THEN '4'
     ELSE cat_order
END)
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, In your case statement you have numeric (4-1) and string values '4'.
There is no default case statement, so if your  cat_order is numeric field in table db, check default value. it must be a 0,  so  zeros are coming from table db column default value, and it not related to your case statement.

Comment: Agree - there are more problems here than alluded to by just the question.

Comment: the math is in there because the actual code is PHP where the math is 1/2 a vairable.